# How should I place an apostrophe to represent the possession on a word already emphasized by rounded apostrophe?

Tags: punctuation, apostrophe

For example:

```
/*!
 * Get the index of specified 'pick_value_item'.
 * @param a0 The path of the 'pick_value_item'.
 * @return The index.
 * @remark The 'path' syntax will be '<page>/<pick_value_item>/<value_item_name>'.
*/
virtual int get_index(std::string)=0;
```

If I don't want to use the *{sth} of '{other}'* pattern, how should I place an apostrophe to represent the possession on a word already emphasized by rounded apostrophes:

> "@param a0 'pick_value_item's path?"

Like that? I guess no one can understand it.

Comment: Why is *pick_value_item* in quotes in the first place?

Comment: Because I want to mark it as a variable in my source code, not an English vocabulary or other proper noun.